# Unable to resolve “./getNextTriggerDateAsync” from “node_modules\expo-notifications\build\index.js”

Tags: react-native, expo

I am developing an using expo, i get this error after importing expo-notifications

```
1-SDK Version: 39.0.3
2-Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): Android/iOS
2-expo-notifications : ~0.7.2
```

```
Unable to resolve "./getNextTriggerDateAsync" from "node_modules\expo-notifications\build\index.js"

undefined Unable to resolve module `./getNextTriggerDateAsync` from `node_modules\expo-notifications\build\index.js`: 

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules\expo-notifications\build\getNextTriggerDateAsync(.native|.android.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.android.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.android.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.android.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm|.android.svg|.native.svg|.svg)
  * node_modules\expo-notifications\build\getNextTriggerDateAsync\index(.native|.android.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.android.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.android.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.android.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm|.android.svg|.native.svg|.svg)
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\HMRClient.js:320:31 in showCompileError
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\HMRClient.js:227:26 in client.on$argument_1
- node_modules\eventemitter3\index.js:181:21 in emit
- node_modules\metro\src\lib\bundle-modules\HMRClient.js:142:10 in _ws.onmessage
- node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to SDK 40 seems to solve this problem

https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-40-is-now-available-d4d73e67da33